# Why is Groovy's rosmake so slow?

Tags: rosmake, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

After upgrading from Fuerte to Groovy (debian packages under Ubuntu 12.04) I have found rosmake runs much slower than it used to.  For example, for one of my typical stacks including 7 packages and mostly Python code, rosmake takes 7.9 seconds under Fuerte and 149 seconds (2 min 29 sec) under Groovy. That's 18x slower(!).  Is this expected?

Thanks,
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54688/why-is-groovy%27s-rosmake-so-slow?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess groovy's rosmake is so slow because rospack is so slow now. This is also the topic of [this Q/A](http://answers.ros.org/question/53925/rospack-became-agonizingly-slow/#53946). Would of course be very interesting if any improvements are planned as this affects a lot of people.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-02-09**:
Thanks @Stefan Kohlbrecher.  I didn't see a ticket on this problem so I logged one here: https://github.com/ros/rosdep/issues/218

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-02-20**:
A recent patch has greatly improved rosmake performance for my test package under Groovy--from 149 seconds to 22 seconds.  Thanks @tfoote and the author of the patch!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I confirm the patch mentioned above also worked for us, reduced the compilation time of almost empty packages by a factor of almost 5.
For the lazy, here is the list of instructions to install it.

```
sudo apt-get install python-jsonpickle --yes
cd /usr/share/pyshared/rosdep2/ 
sudo rm sources_list.py 
sudo wget https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdep/b0aaeb0fd1e12c6e857d7ebe1785c61f90df5a5a/src/rosdep2/sources_list.py 
rosdep update  
rosmake <package>
```

---

Originally posted by [anonymous2054](https://answers.ros.org/users/2054/anonymous2054/) with karma: 101 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [afourast](https://answers.ros.org/users/2974/afourast/) on 2013-03-25**:
On my system the source_list.py file that rosdep uses is located in  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosdep2 , instead of the directory specified
(ubuntu 12.04, installed from debian package)
The patch improved things a bit but is I think still quite slow compared to fuerte or catkin